# How to open Excel file using Nodejs and Rest API

Tags: node.js, excel

[image: i have added the error screenshot that i am getting]

I am new to Nodejs programming, i want to develop a web API in order to open a excel file and get that data from excel on web browser and later transfer that data to Mysql database.
How should i create it.
I have tried this project from [github](https://github.com/rahil471/excel-to-json-in-Node.js)

but they are uploading using html, i don't want that html part, i want to give excel file path directly in .js code file.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [this](https://github.com/rahil471/excel-to-json-in-Node.js) project the following thing implemented

1) Install module

```
npm install xlsx
```

2) Put books.xlsx file in "uploads" folder

3) Changes in code

```
var XLSX = require('xlsx');
```

Add above line below to

> require('multer');

then delete

> app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

then finally add below code

```
app.all('/upload', function(req, res) {
    var workbook = XLSX.readFile(__dirname + '/uploads/books.xlsx');
    var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
    var xlData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);
    console.log(xlData);
    res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null, data: xlData});
});
```

4) Finally click Upload button you will get the result as json or use this link to check the result "http://localhost:3000/upload"

NOTE: Negative scenario not implemented and check for coding standrds

### For Insert into Table

```
npm install mysql
```

create a file name called **dbconfig.js** and add the following code in to that file

```
  var mysql = require('mysql');
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    database:"test" // Your database name here
  });
  connection.connect(function(error){
    if(error)
      throw error;
    else{
      console.log('Connected!!');
    }
  });
  module.exports = connection;
```

Add following lines below to

> var xlData =
>   XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);

in app.js file

```
var con = require('./dbconfig');
var query = con.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', postvalues, function(err, result) {
        if(err)
          throw err
        else{
          console.log('Successfully inserted');      
        }
      });
```

I used table users, in your case use your table name

Comment: Thank you this code worked for me, just one more thing is there any way to push this data from excel file into Mysql database within this same code.

Comment: sure i will. Any thoughts on Mysql thing.

Comment: please check the screenshot that i have added in my question, i am getting that error after making the changes.

Comment: Try to learn basics of Nodejs then fallen into coding ... 
change app.post to "app.all(" in app.js

Comment: i have defined postvalues as " var postvalues = "values"; " now i am not getting any error values are coming but they are not going into the mysql table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188812/discussion-between-rasa-mohamed-and-vishruti).